# Laravel unit testing of controllers

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I am trying to start a new Laravel app following TDD

My first step is to check that the /login controller is called on the home url.

Despite following several tutorials I can't get the test to work and I can't see what I'm doing wrong at all.

My set up is:
composer to install laravel
composer to install phpunit

here is my route:

```
<?php
Route::get('/login', 'AuthenticationController@login');
```

my controller:

```
<?php

class AuthenticationController extends BaseController {

    public function login () {
        return View::make('authentication.login');
    }

}
```

And my test:

```
<?php

class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase {

    public function testSomeTest () {

        $response = $this->action('GET', 'AuthenticationController@login');

        $view = $response->original;

        $this->assertEquals('authentication.login', $view['name']);
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
  ErrorException: Undefined index: name
```

The code as a copy (pretty much exactly) from the Laravel site, yet it doesn't run.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

It claims $view has no index name, but that can't be right as its the example on the laravel website, plus the view is being rendered using its name (it is showing correctly on the front end too)

EDIT::

So it seems from a comment that the laravel unit testing section isn't clear and that the $view['name'] is checking for a variable called $name. If that is the case, how do you test the controller/route used, IE. what controller name/action name has been used for route('X')

Comment: `$view['name']` is not the name of the view but the variable `$name` that is available on your view. But you don't pass anything to it. In your controller, it should be e.g. `return View::make('authentication.login')->with('name', 'John');`, and then you want to test if `$name` is available from the view and contains 'John': `$this->assertEquals('John', $view['name']);`.

Comment: Really? Then the docs are misleading. How then can I test that either my controller i fire on a certain route? Or how would I get the name of the controller/action used for a certain route?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want to unit test your application, this does not involve testing if a route calls the right controller method or the controller loads the correct view. This is part of Laravel's functionality and it's already tested. You want to test if the right methods within your controller are called and what the response is. You don't need to test which route calls which controller method, you just call the route that triggers the controller method you actually want to test.

Comment: I guess that make sense. my thinking was that id write a test that the login action would be called form the default/home route. then I'd check that another route redirected to the login route IF the user isnt logged in. but If I can't get the route or controller being used how would I test if a unauthorised user was redirected to the login route/controller?      I suppose  $response = $this->call('GET', 'admin/users'); $this->assertRedirectedTo('admin/login'); is about the only thing I can do (although it does do what I'd want.

Comment: just assumed there was a clear way to say "i've gone to x url, what controller to I get?"

Comment: Yes, because that's what you want to test. In your unit test, all you want to know is if the right actions are triggered depending on whether the user is logged in or not. In your case, you check if the response is a redirect to a certain route. And that's it. You don't care what happens after that or which controller is called - that is way beyond the scope of your unit test. You just want to check if your application gives the expected responses for the given input. Set up an authenticated user, call the route and check if you're redirected to 'admin/users', otherwise e.g. to 'user/login'.

Comment: Maybe this will help to clarify the difference between, unit, integration and acceptance testing: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456

Comment: Thanks, can you add the above as an answer and I'll set it as it has answered my issues. cheers

Comment: Unit testing should not test anything outside of your codebase.  If you have dependencies, mock them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update, 2020-07-01:**

Since this answer seems to still get some upvotes every now and then, I just want to point out that **I do not consider this to be a good testing approach** anymore. Laravel has massively improved on the testing experience since v4 and there was a pretty significant overall paradigm shift, away from units and classes and more towards features and endpoints. That is not only an idiomatic change but also seems to make way more sense from a technical perspective.

Also, a lot of new and useful testing helpers that allow for less brittle tests have been introduced since then. Please refer to the documentation for an overwiew and basic test examples.

---

Ok, as already explained a little in the comments, let's first take a step back and think about the scenario.

> "My first step is to check that the /login controller is called on the home url."

So that means: When the user hits the home route, you want to check if the user is logged in. If he's not, you want to redirect them to the login, maybe with some flash message. After they have logged in, you want to redirect them back to the home page. If the login fails, you want to redirect them back to the login form, maybe also with a flash message.

So there are several things to test now: The home controller and the login controller. So following the TDD spirit, let's create the tests first.

*Note: I'll follow some naming convention that is used by [phpspec](http://www.phpspec.net/), but don't let that bother you.*

```
class HomeControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_redirects_to_login_if_user_is_not_authenticated()
    {
        Auth::shouldReceive('check')->once()->andReturn(false);

        $response = $this->call('GET', 'home');
        
        // Now we have several ways to go about this, choose the
        // one you're most comfortable with.

        // Check that you're redirecting to a specific controller action 
        // with a flash message
        $this->assertRedirectedToAction(
             'AuthenticationController@login', 
             null, 
             ['flash_message']
        );
        
        // Only check that you're redirecting to a specific URI
        $this->assertRedirectedTo('login');

        // Just check that you don't get a 200 OK response.
        $this->assertFalse($response->isOk());

        // Make sure you've been redirected.
        $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirection());
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_returns_home_page_if_user_is_authenticated()
    {
        Auth::shouldReceive('check')->once()->andReturn(true);

        $this->call('GET', 'home');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

And that's it for the Home controller. In most cases you actually don't care where you are redirected to, because that may change over time and you would have to change the tests. So the least you should do is to check whether you are being redirected or not and only check for more details if you really think that it matters for your test.

Let's have a look at the Authentication controller:

```
class AuthenticationControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_shows_the_login_form()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'login');

        $this->assertTrue($response->isOk());

        // Even though the two lines above may be enough,
        // you could also check for something like this:

        View::shouldReceive('make')->with('login');
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_redirects_back_to_form_if_login_fails()
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ];

        Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
             ->once()
             ->with($credentials)
             ->andReturn(false);

        $this->call('POST', 'login', $credentials);

        $this->assertRedirectedToAction(
            'AuthenticationController@login', 
            null, 
            ['flash_message']
        );
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_redirects_to_home_page_after_user_logs_in()
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ];

        Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
             ->once()
             ->with($credentials)
             ->andReturn(true);

        $this->call('POST', 'login', $credentials);

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('home');
    }
}
```

Again, always think about what you really want to test. Do you *really* need to know which controller action is triggered on which route? Or what the name of the view is that is returned? Actually, you just need to make sure that the controller actually *attempts* to do it. You pass it some data and then test if it behaves as expected.

And always make sure you're not trying to test any framework functionality, for instance if a specific route triggers a specific action or if a View is loaded correctly. This has already been tested, so you don't need to worry about that. Focus on the functionality of your application and not on the underlying framework.

Comment: Did you have any problem with mocking `Auth::shouldReceive('check')` method? When I tried execute your test method with that method I get `driver() does not exist on this mock object`

Comment: @extra90 Yes, it works fine, and it's the documented way of mocking facades: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades. Sounds like you have no session or auth driver set.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yeah I have custom auth driver. Do you know how then mock check method and custom driver?

Comment: @extra90 Sorry, I don't know much about that. Maybe looking at how the framework itself does it might help: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php - In short, it just swaps out the 'auth' container binding with a mock. Actually, this should work for any driver... But I've never worked with other drivers, so I'm afraid I can't really help you out.

Comment: Yeah, maybe is also problem with Session driver like you mentioned. When I try with `Auth attempt` method works fine.  What is best way to mock Session driver?

Comment: @extra90 Sorry, as I said, I've never worked with other drivers, so I can't really help you.

Comment: Im getting Fatal error: Stack overflow in vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php on line 1249

Comment: this seems like Acceptance Test Driven Development instead of TDD, TDD is about Unit Testing.

Comment: @PabloMorales What are you talking about? TDD is about... well... letting tests drive your development process. Where does it say that this is limited to unit testing (which wouldn't even make sense here)? A test is a test, choose whatever is appropriate and don't stand in your own light by just religiously trying to live up to some abstract terminology. If you have to hit the database in your unit test, go ahead and hit the database if it makes sense - nothing wrong with that! No matter what you call it, it's still a perfectly valid and most importantly **useful** test, not just a spellcheck.